# how to send object when i pop? (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Context: I'm creating an app for sales and when I'm on the sales screen I have a button (Add item), this button takes me to the items grid.

my difficulty is turning on the sales screen with the selected item.

```
onTap: () => isSelecting ? Navigator.of(context).pop() : null,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
Navigator.pop(context, yourObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onPressed: () async {
                     newProduto = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProdutosPage(selecting: true)));
                     setState(() {
                       produtos.add(newProduto);
                     });
                    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?